Dynamic tables at runtime in Haskell Persistent
I'm trying to work out if there is a way one can have a have a runtime flag, that is able to dictate the shape of the schema.
Let's say my runtime flag is Config, as you can see in my hypothetical code I'm able to adjust the schema using the @. I'm aware this looks like a feature request but could there be a way to handle this behaviour given the current implementation of Persistent?
data Config = ConfigA | ConfigB

share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"] [persistLowerCase|
User
  name String
  age Int @ConfigA
  email String @ConfigB
  department DepartmentId @ConfigA
  team TeamId @ConfigB
  deriving Show

Department @ConfigA
  name String
  location String
  deriving Show

Team @ConfigB
  name String
  project String
  deriving Show

Post
  title String
  content String
  author UserId
  deriving Show
|]

